# Polymer components Shady DOM styles are simply comments on production

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, shady-dom

I have been chasing this error for a while. On development everything is working well, when pushed to Heroku for production it is not. I am using sails on the backend but that is not an issue since this is a client side problem. Worst part is this has been working and only broke a couple days ago. Tracing my steps back did not prove to find the cause.

Long story short pictures may help in case anyone has seen this before.

When loading the app on production these errors start showing up"

[image: Console errors]

This was confusing as I was not getting this locally on development. Having run into issues in the past with js concat and minification I turned that off for production. Still same errors. Then I noticed this difference between the head of production and development:

**Production:**
[image: Production head showing shady DOM]

**Development**

[image: Development head showing shady Dom]

Next I checked my links to the polymer components I am adding on load and dynamically for the initial page. Both production an development were the same:

[image: Polymer imports]

Next I tried dynamically importing a polymer component using `Polymer.Base.importHref('/vendor/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html')`. After importing the shady DOM styles added to the head was different for production and development

**Production:**

[image: Added shady dom style production]

**Development:**

[image]

Lastly when I then created a paper-checkbox element with `document.createElement('paper-checkbox')` things worked fine locally on development. On production, error as before:

[image]

I am stuck here. If anyone has seen this before and has insight I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem, though there may be another issue that will need to checked with Polymer. In my many deploys I noticed in one of the build logs that the version number installed for Polymer was different than what I had in my `bower.json` file and local system. The minor version jumped from 1.3.1 to 1.4.0. My `bower.json` used ^ instead of ~. The ^ allows changes to all but the leftmost version number while the ~ only allows patch level changes.

Original `bower.json`:

[image: Original bower.json]

New `bower.json`:

[image: New bower.json]

Thought I would give it a try. Once I deployed polymer 1.3.1 was installed and my site was back up and working. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.